# How to detect the url is redirected from another link

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm actually creating a browser add-on for Chrome/Firefox.

I found that a lot of shopping-guide websites will add some parameters in the url if the user clicks the shopping website's link. Like if you click an Amazon link on a shopping guide website, the final url will be `http://www.amazon.com/?tag=xxxx`. I guess this way the shopping guide website can make money if you purchase on it.

Well I want to inform the user about this. If they have been redirected from a shopping guide website, show an alert.

How to detect this? I've tried `document.referrer`, it's empty. And not every shopping guide website uses the same parameters, so I think to detect whether it's redirected would be the best way.

For example in this website: https://istreet.org.uk/shops, click a shop link, it will open a page and then the url changes to the shop website.

Comment: Check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Comment: @www139 As I said, I tried this, not working.